# igraph: plot only edges, no vertices

Tags: r, networking, igraph

I would like to plot an `igraph` object without vertices. Simply specifying `vertex.color = "white"` does not help much as the vertices overlap due to a very high number of vertices. `vertex.size = 0` plots small vertices, See plot 1 on the left. I have tried `vertex.size = (-1)` which produces the error:

```
Error in symbols(x = coords[, 1], y = coords[, 2], bg = vertex.color,  : 
  invalid symbol parameter
```

even though it plots no vertices (or they are so small to be invisible?) in the following Plot 2 on the right:

***Plot 1 and 2***

[image: Plot 1][image: Plot 2]

data and code:

```
g <- make_ring(10) 
plot(g,vertex.size = 0) # plot 1
plot(g,vertex.size = (-1)) # plot 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want can be achieved using multiple vertex options:

```r
library(igraph)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'igraph'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     decompose, spectrum
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     union
g <- make_ring(10) 

plot(g,
     vertex.shape = 'none',
     vertex.size = 0,
     vertex.label= NA)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

For other options see `help("igraph.plotting")`